# how do I find the coordinates on the ellipse where tangent vector is perpendicular to the position vector?

Tags: vector-analysis

The parametric equation of an ellipse with semi-axes a and b is r(t) = (a cost, b sint), where t ∈ [0,2π). Assuming that a≠ b, find the coordinates of all points on the ellipse where the tangent vector r ̇(t) is perpendicular to the position vector r(t).

I have found r ̇(t)= (-a sint,b cost) but I don't know where to go from there. How is the tangent vector perpendicular to r(t) isn't it tangent?

Comment: The position vector is anchored at the origin. The tangent vector is tangent to the curve, not the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: to tell when two vectors are perpendicular, take the dot product and see when it is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the ellipse is a circle there are only 4 points: 2 at x=0 and 2 at y=0. To see this look at the parametric equation for ellips:
$$x = a\cos t\;\;\;\; y = b\sin t$$
$$\dot x = -a \sin t\;\;\;\;\dot y = b \cos t$$
Tangent is orthogonal to the position vector when $x\dot x + y\dot y = 0$, or
$(b-a)\sin t\cos t=0$. But if $b \neq a$ it is equivalent to $\sin 2t=0$, or
$t = \frac{n\pi}{2}$ where $0\leq n < 4$.